# Does this video show a sniper shooting a Palestinian?

Tags: military, video, palestine

In this troubling [not suitable for all audiences] [video](https://www.youtube.com/v/sBakqLUBWP0), you see a young man being shot.

There were [many claims on Reddit that it was fake](http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/2bb0lu/cellphone_video_captures_gaza_civilian_shot_and/cj3s0tv), and [then claims that it was real](http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/2bh76w/the_video_of_a_young_unarmed_gazan_man_shot_dead/).

Is there a way to know for sure if this is real or not?

I personally have no clue (this is why I post it here)

Is there a scientific way to prove / disprove it is real / fake?

Obviously, this is a sensitive video and discretion is suggested. I'd be terribly sad if it is indeed real. My condolences to this person's family, and I condemn whomever shot him, if it turns out real.

Comment: Scientific, no, but it's certainly possible to give more context to a piece of information to understand its origin.

Comment: The [Telegraph  reports](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/palestinianauthority/10983362/Palestinian-activists-accused-of-faking-Israeli-sniper-shooting-video.html) that someone analyzed the video frame by frame and you can tell that it is staged. The supposed uncut video has clear edits (time of day changes, moving rubble/chairs, theatrical squibs that don't have the time delay between the impact of a sniper found and the sound, inconsistent damage from Israeli weapons, etc.

Comment: Debunking is done for the video part by Thomas Wictor here-http://www.thomaswictor.com/gaza-sniper-video-definitively-debunked/ and the counterpoint by Eran Efrati  a former sergeant in the Israeli Defense Force here-http://www.spokesmanbooks.com/Spokesman/PDF/126Efrati.pdf.

Comment: @pericles316 The thomaswictor site is currently unavailable, but from what i can see on the waybackmachine, the author seems more than a little unhinged. There are lots of pictures with arrows in them, but nothing that is clear. the only clear 'evidence' ( a side by side of the same shadow in two different images, implying a time delay) is only that clear because one of the chose images is from a videoframe where the shadow is extremely vague. There are more frames adjacent, where the shadow is clear - and totally benign. This leaves me to question whether the site is arguing in good faith.